# How to create an Observable from query?

Tags: angular, rxjs, electron, observable, nosql

How can I get an rxjs-observable in angular 2 from an async LinvoDB database query in electron?

in the main process:

```
exports.load = function(parameters){
    var l = parseInt(parameters.l);
    var t = parseInt(parameters.t);
    var r = parseInt(parameters.r);
    var b = parseInt(parameters.b);
    return cmelement.find({
            $or: [
                {$and: [{x0: { $gt: l, $lt: r }}, {y0: { $gt: t, $lt: b }}]},
                {$and: [{x1: { $gt: l, $lt: r }}, {y1: { $gt: t, $lt: b }}]}
            ]
        }).filter(function(x){ return x !== undefined })
        .exec(function (err, doc) {
            console.log(doc); // outputs the correct data
            return doc;
        });
};
```

in the renderer process I use electron.remote to access the function:

```
getElements(parameters) {
    Observable.of(elementController.load(parameters))
              .subscribe((x) => console.log(x)); // outputs 'undefined'
  }
```

Besides this I tried a variety of other methods like declaring the observable as a variable and merging the results from db, setting the query as live(), getting the data via ipc.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your entire load function into returning an Observable:

```
exports.load = function(parameters){
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    var l = parseInt(parameters.l);
    var t = parseInt(parameters.t);
    var r = parseInt(parameters.r);
    var b = parseInt(parameters.b);
    return cmelement.find({
            $or: [
                {$and: [{x0: { $gt: l, $lt: r }}, {y0: { $gt: t, $lt: b }}]},
                {$and: [{x1: { $gt: l, $lt: r }}, {y1: { $gt: t, $lt: b }}]}
            ]
        }).filter(function(x){ return x !== undefined })
        .exec(function (err, doc) {
            console.log(doc); // outputs the correct data
            observer.next(doc);
            observer.complete();
        });
  });
};
```

Then in your getElements function:

```
getElements(parameters) {
    elementController.load(parameters)
      .subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
  }
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Thank you very much, worked perfectly with your code.

Comment: Please @Patrick if you are satisfied mark this answer as the correct one! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it, but would assume something like this:

```js
exports.load = function(parameters, subject){
    var l = parseInt(parameters.l);
    var t = parseInt(parameters.t);
    var r = parseInt(parameters.r);
    var b = parseInt(parameters.b);
    return cmelement.find({
            $or: [
                {$and: [{x0: { $gt: l, $lt: r }}, {y0: { $gt: t, $lt: b }}]},
                {$and: [{x1: { $gt: l, $lt: r }}, {y1: { $gt: t, $lt: b }}]}
            ]
        }).filter(function(x){ return x !== undefined })
        .exec(function (err, doc) {
            console.log(doc); // outputs the correct data

            // fire your subject here .. !
            subject && subject.next && subject.next(doc) && subject.complete();

            return doc;
        });
};

getElements(parameters) {
   const subj = new Subject<any /* or your type.. */>();
   elementController.load(parameters, subj);

   // return your subject here or subscribe to it..
   subj.subscribe(doc => console.log(doc));
}
```